# How to generate stale flag using analytic functions Pyspark?

Tags: function, pyspark

What is the efficient way to create below output table with minimal join and by using the analytic functions?

expiry_date - Date until the answer is valid.

stale_answer_flag - Flag on the child answer showing that it predates the parent answer

**Input tables:**

**Question:**

| question_id | parent_question_id | question |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Are you living in the US? |
| 1A | 1 | What is your state |

**Answer:**

| question_id | date | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-sept-2022 | yes |
| 1A | 01-sept-2022 | NY |
| 1 | 05-sept-2022 | yes |

**Expected Output table:**

| question_id | parent_question_id | question | answer | date | expiry_date | stale_ans_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Are you living in the US? | Yes | 01-sept-2022 | 05-sept-2022 | Y |
| 1A | 1 | What is your state | NY | 01-sept-2022 | 'NULL' | N |
| 1 |  | Are you living in the US? | Yes | 05-sept-2022 | 'NULL' | N |

Comment: It sounds you want to do a SCD2 Type historization of your rows if there comes an update for the same key? If yes you should use one of the data formats that can handle upsers and merges like delta, hudi or iceberg. If not the only way is to run multible joins to create the update row and union them with the new row

Answer (score 1):

A standard SCD2 can be done the following

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from  pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# create some data, I added a user column to also add new entries
data_1 = [
    ("alex","1","2022-09-01","yes"),
    ("alex","1A","2022-09-01","NY"),
    ]

schema = ["user","id","date","answer"]
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_1, schema = schema)
df_1.show(truncate=False)

+----+---+----------+------+
|user|id |date      |answer|
+----+---+----------+------+
|alex|1  |2022-09-01|yes   |
|alex|1A |2022-09-01|NY    |
+----+---+----------+------+


data_2 = [
    ("alex","1","2022-09-05","no"),
    ("john","1","2022-09-05","yes"),
    ("john","1A","2022-09-05","VA")
]

schema = ["user","id","date","answer"]
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_2, schema = schema)
df_2.show(truncate=False)

+----+---+----------+------+
|user|id |date      |answer|
+----+---+----------+------+
|alex|1  |2022-09-05|no    |
|john|1  |2022-09-05|yes   |
|john|1A |2022-09-05|VA    |
+----+---+----------+------+


# create the initial dataset of the "old" data with the two additional columns
df_old=(df_1
                .withColumn("expiry_date",f.lit(None).cast(DateType()))
                .withColumn("stale_ans_flag",f.lit(False))
)

df_old.show()

+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
|user| id|      date|answer|expiry_date|stale_ans_flag|
+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
|alex|  1|2022-09-01|   yes|       null|         false|
|alex| 1A|2022-09-01|    NY|       null|         false|
+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+

# create a new column on the new dataset that will update the old one
df_new=(df_2
                .withColumn("expiry_date",f.lit(None).cast(DateType()))
                .withColumn("stale_ans_flag",f.lit(False))
)

df_new.show()
+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
|user| id|      date|answer|expiry_date|stale_ans_flag|
+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
|alex|  1|2022-09-05|    no|       null|         false|
|john|  1|2022-09-05|   yes|       null|         false|
|john| 1A|2022-09-05|    VA|       null|         false|
+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+

# now join both together on the relevant keys and add an helper column
df_merge=(df_old.alias("old")
          # a full outer join makes it easy to compare new and old and create manual update strategies
          .join(df_new.alias("new"),
               (df_old.user == df_new.user) &
               (df_old.id == df_new.id),
                how='fullouter'
               )
          # helper columns, you can do it without but due to lazy evaluatiuon it does not matter but helps reading the code and debugging
          .withColumn("_action",f.when(
                # identify new records that have to be inserted
                 (f.col("old.user").isNull())
               & (f.col("old.id").isNull())
               & (f.col("new.user").isNotNull())
               & (f.col("new.id").isNotNull())
               , "new"
            ).when(
                # identify old records that are not changed
                 (f.col("old.user").isNotNull())
               & (f.col("old.id").isNotNull())
               & (f.col("new.user").isNull())
               & (f.col("new.id").isNull())
               , "old"
            ).when(
                # identify update records 
                 (f.col("old.user").isNotNull())
               & (f.col("old.id").isNotNull())
               & (f.col("new.user").isNotNull())
               & (f.col("new.id").isNotNull())
               , "update"
          )
                     )
          
          
)
df_merge.show()

+----+----+----------+------+-----------+--------------+----+----+----------+------+-----------+--------------+-------+
|user|  id|      date|answer|expiry_date|stale_ans_flag|user|  id|      date|answer|expiry_date|stale_ans_flag|_action|
+----+----+----------+------+-----------+--------------+----+----+----------+------+-----------+--------------+-------+
|null|null|      null|  null|       null|          null|john|  1A|2022-09-05|    VA|       null|         false|    new|
|alex|   1|2022-09-01|   yes|       null|         false|alex|   1|2022-09-05|    no|       null|         false| update|
|alex|  1A|2022-09-01|    NY|       null|         false|null|null|      null|  null|       null|          null|    old|
|null|null|      null|  null|       null|          null|john|   1|2022-09-05|   yes|       null|         false|    new|
+----+----+----------+------+-----------+--------------+----+----+----------+------+-----------+--------------+-------+

# finally put all together with a union
df_merge_union=( df_merge
    #first take the old ones of the dataset that did not change and are kept as they are
    .filter(f.col("_action")=="old")
    .select("old.user",
            "old.id",
            "old.date",
            "old.answer",
            "old.expiry_date",
            "old.stale_ans_flag"
           )
    # than add the brand new ones that did not exist before
    .union(df_merge
        .filter(f.col("_action")=="new")
        .select("new.user",
                "new.id",
                "new.date",
                "new.answer",
                "new.expiry_date",
                "new.stale_ans_flag"
               )
            )
    # add the old row with the old values that has been updated and change the flag
    .union(df_merge
        .filter(f.col("_action")=="update")
        .select("old.user",
                "old.id",
                "old.date",
                "old.answer",
                "new.date", # or f.current_date(),
                f.lit(True)
               )
            )
    # add the old row with the new values that has been updated
    .union(df_merge
        .filter(f.col("_action")=="update")
        .select("new.user",
                "new.id",
                "new.date",
                "new.answer",
                f.lit(None),
                f.lit(False)
               )
            )
    
)

df_merge_union.sort("user","id").show()

+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
|user| id|      date|answer|expiry_date|stale_ans_flag|
+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
|alex|  1|2022-09-01|   yes| 2022-09-05|          true|
|alex|  1|2022-09-05|    no|       null|         false|
|alex| 1A|2022-09-01|    NY|       null|         false|
|john|  1|2022-09-05|   yes|       null|         false|
|john| 1A|2022-09-05|    VA|       null|         false|
+----+---+----------+------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in my case, I am having nested questions, based on my parent question response date, stale answer flag should be created(denoting that it predates the parent answer).

Comment: Please explain it better, I do not understand based on your sample data set and your comment what you are intending to do